# Excel VBA maxter data

Tags: excel, vba

I used this code for copy the cells to a master data. The data in the cell contains formulas. How can I paste this data in the other sheet changing the format of the cell to a number.??

```
Sub MaxterData()

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E2").Copy


Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Summary Info").Activate
Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub MaxterData()

Dim lastrow As Long

With Sheets("Summary Info")
    lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Resize(, 4).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E2")
    .Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Resize(, 4).NumberFormat = "General"
End With

End Sub
```

Try to avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate`.  Most of the time it is not needed and only slows done the code.

Also when only wanting the values assign the values directly to the target.

Comment: He is only pasting the values not the formatting as I can see it. @findwindow

Comment: @findwindow yes, I can see where I missed something. give me a second.